# Fullscreen App, Layout shifted down by height of notification bar

Tags: android

I have an App that has a toolbar at the bottom of the screen and the rest is filled with a custom View (see xml below). Now when I make the App full screen (I tried all possibilities, programmatically and via Manifest.xml), when it's started the whole layout seems to be shifted down by about the height of the notification bar. The buttons in the toolbar are only visible half-way. Sometimes, all of it moves up after a few seconds, or when I click a button in the toolbar.

[image]

I'm pretty sure, that it's a problem with my custom view, because I do not get this effect if I replace it with a Button or the like. I guess it must have something to do with the `onMeasure` method. I don't really know how to implement it, my version is shown below. The custom view is used for drawing inside, so basically it wants to be as large as possible.

Any help would be much appreciated. I searched for several hours already, but no clue yet.

**layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <com.example.MyCanvasView 
        android:id="@+id/canvas" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
         />
    <!-- Buttonbar -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@android:drawable/bottom_bar"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
        />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2"
        />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my `onMeasure` method:

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}
```

Comment: Have you set the style of the application or the specific activity to something that has no title bar/no notification bar?

Comment: I tried both. Setting the NoTitle.Fullscreen theme in the manifest file, and also setting if programmatically. It's the same for both. It works as far as no title bar is shown and the notification bar disappears animated towards the top.

Comment: Any chance you could post a screen shot of what it looks like? Are you using the emulator or a device?

Comment: @Treebranch, I added the screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason for the described behaviour. I had set the view to be focusable in touchmode via `setFocusableInTouchMode(true)` in the `onCreate()` method. As soon as I removed this, it works fine. Thanks to adamp though -- your description of what goes on during layout and measuring was very interesting.

But that leaves me with the problem that I do not receive any key/button clicks any more :-(

Comment: Interesting! I'm able to reproduce this in a small test app on Gingerbread. I'll have to check next week but you may have found a framework bug. What is it you're trying to do with key/button events? This can probably be worked around.

Comment: Hm, almost makes me a little bit proud, that I might have found a bug :-)  In fact it was quite stupid of me, that I tried getting the key events in this View. I just wanted to hear of the back button to do some undo. I simply moved that to the onKeyEvent() method of the actual Activity and that was it :-)

Comment: Great, glad you were able to find a solution that works for your app. :)

Answer (score 2):

You're not taking the mode into account when you're setting your measurement.

The mode of a [`MeasureSpec`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.MeasureSpec.html) can be one of `MeasureSpec.EXACTLY`, `MeasureSpec.AT_MOST`, or `MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED`. Simply accepting the size component and setting your measured size to that is appropriate for `EXACTLY`, but it isn't often the right thing for the others.

Because you're trying to use `layout_weight` in addition to a height of `wrap_content` on this custom view, the following is happening:

Your custom view is the first child of the LinearLayout with a height of `wrap_content` so `LinearLayout` measures it. Since `LinearLayout` has been told by the `LayoutParams` that it should `wrap_content`, it measures your custom view with a `MeasureSpec` mode of `AT_MOST` and a size of the entire available space.

But your custom view is greedy. It decides to take all of the space available. In essence, you have implemented your measurement to treat `wrap_content` as `match_parent`.

Now there's no more space left. The lower button bar gets measured accordingly but it's not done yet, there's a child with weight. In a `LinearLayout` any space left over after all normal measurement is complete is divided among the weighted children according to their weight values. This isn't the behavior you want.

When you use weight to fill available vertical space like you're doing in this layout, you normally want to set the `layout_height` to `0dip`. This will make `LinearLayout` skip the first measure pass on that child and only use the weighted measurement pass to measure your view, giving it the remaining available space.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It sounds logical, but it's doesn't help with my problem. You see, the view gets the correct height, but the whole window seems to be shifted down. Besides, when I replace my custom view with a `Button` and have the `layout_height` and `layout_weight` as in my layout.xml, everything works out fine.